# t:datatable row expantion and detail using ajax

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, tomahawk

I have a view similar to below screenshot. Which is buildup using **t:datatable**.

Now, What I need to do is, If I click on link **101** It needs to call Ajax and open further details between these two rows. I mean in between **101** and **102**.

Is it possible to put these kind of rows | columns in **t:datatable** ?
 Appreciate your help guys.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in `DataGrid` from RichFaces, it seems can fit you well.

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataGrid&skin=blueSky